# get context object from ComponentName object

Tags: android, service, components, toast, android-context

I need to get current running Activity and detect it in the Service. I do it in that way:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ServiceMessages.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo >   taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
componentInfo.getPackageName();
Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + componentInfo.getClassName());
```

and get the name of running Activity successfully. But I need to pass Toast message to that Activity. So, I need to pass Context object of current Activity to  `Toast.makeText(context,text, length)` . How can I get the context object if I have ComponentName?

Comment: You could pass a singleton reference to your Application context. Toast will work with an Application context.

Comment: do you mean getApplicationContext() ? if I do like this, nothing is happened...